# Converting ArrayList to String to store in Shared Preferences

Tags: java, android, string, arraylist, sharedpreferences

i have ArrayList with multiple value. i want to convert this ArrayList into String to save in sharedPreferences, then I want to retrieve the String and convert it back to ArrayList

Please tell how to do that? (or any other idea to store and retrieve ArrayList)

Comment: You should at least include some code snippet of where you are stuck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert arraylist to string:

```
String str = "";

for (String s : arraylist)
{
    str += s + ",";
}
```

Save string into sharedpreference:

```
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).edit().putString("mystr", str).commit();
```

get string from sharedpreference:

```
String str =    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).getString("mystr", "defaultStringIfNothingFound");
```

Convert string to arraylist:

```
List<String> arraylist = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(str.split(",")));
```

Comment: Note:- This works only for Arraylist of type String, ArrayList can be of  any type. 
The question points at ArrayList<CustomClass>

Answer (score 3):

You can use Google's GSON.

> Gson is a Java library that can be used to convert Java Objects into
>   their JSON representation. It can also be used to convert a JSON
>   string to an equivalent Java object. Gson can work with arbitrary Java
>   objects including pre-existing objects that you do not have
>   source-code of.

http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/Gson.html

https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

You get the idea:

> - Store: Convert Object to JSON String -> Save string
> - Retrieve: Get string -> Convert from JSON to Object

Comment: but gson is deprecated

Comment: click [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/downloads/detail?name=google-gson-2.2.4-release.zip&) .. when you click to download then message come